# How to combine different columns from three different tables into one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Please see the picture for reference. I tried doing Union All between the first and second select statements and also between the second and third select statements. So I did two Union All but that did not work.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi, for such questions please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (or https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if it's about db).

Comment: Confused. This isn't MySQL.

Comment: Please don't use images for code or data... use formated text.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `union`, the number of columns and datatype of columns should be the same. So since your last query returns 'character', you have to convert the same column in other the queries into a string:

```
SELECT cast(MLDNBR as varchar(100)), cast(PLTGRN as varchar(100)), NULL as ReleaseID
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[v_Curing_Tooling] 
UNION ALL
SELECT cast(MOLDas varchar(100)), NULL, NULL
FROM [TireTrack].[dbo].[cos_work]
UNION ALL
SELECT Spec, Left (Spec,6) as SpecID, Right (Spec,2) as ReleaseID
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Locator]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, It only returned MLDNBR and PLTGRN and Release ID data into one table but the field names were missing for MLDNBR and PLTGRN. The data for Mold, Spec and SpecID were all lost. They are all supposed to be in table

Answer (score 0):

How is the data in `v_Curing_Tooling`, `cos_work`, and `Locator` related? If they are not related, they would not be on the same row. If they are related, you need an ID to join the tables on.

Example:

```
SELECT MLDNBR, PLTGRN, MOLD, Spec, Left (Spec,6) as 'SpecID', Right (Spec,2) as 'ReleaseID'
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[v_Curing_Tooling] t
    JOIN [TireTrack].[dbo].[cos_work] w ON t.ToolingID = w.ToolingID
    JOIN [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Locator] l ON l.LocationID = t.LocationID
```

I do not know how your tables are related, though, so those JOIN clauses probably need correct join conditions.

Look up [How To Join SQL Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).